# Webservice for receiving information from external source

Tags: asp.net, web-services, webforms

Let me preface this with: This is a webforms project and it is not changing, put away your pitchforks.

We have an application that needs to receive information from an external website (everything here is in the context of intranet). They will be posting to a url that I give them. The URL will contain a query string.

What do I use to accomplish this? I've been looking at webservices, is this the right direction to go? Could someone point me to a good tutorial? Google has not been too helpful here, or rather, I do not know how to ask the question properly.

Comment: them doing a "POST" means you should have a web-service client ready to accept whatever they send.

Comment: Ok, so is there a good tutorial detailing how this is accomplished somewhere? I am coming from an MVC world, so some of this seems a little foreign.Thanks for the reply

Comment: [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/how-to-create-web-api-in-Asp-Net-mvc/) is a good point to start.

Comment: I did not know that I could use MVC with webforms. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from using Web API in a Web Forms project.  Since you come from an MVC environment I'm assuming you're familiar with Web API.

Comment: Yup, I had no clue that I was able to do this. Thank you